# How do I reconfigure my GLES frame buffer after a rotation?

Tags: ios, opengl-es2, opentk, monotouch

*Note: In order to keep the question as simple as possible, I am actively changing the body of the question to reflect the current state of affairs, instead of adding stuff at the bottom.*

I am implementing interface rotation for my GLES based game for iOS, written in Xamarin.iOS with OpenTK.

I am detecting the rotation by overriding `WillRotate`, in my `UIViewController`, and I correctly re-setup all of my projection matrices.

However, the results of drawing a sprite on landscape and portrait modes are slightly different -landscape is a bit blurry-.

This is the test sprite I am using, which is 128x128 to avoid any rounding errors:

[image: Sample image]

My test projection matrix is based on a 1024x768 display for an iPad. Even though I won't be scaling the image, I am using point filtering, so I expect rendering to be pixel perfect. The rendering position is (0, 0) once again to avoid any rounding errors. The sprite should fall exactly into the pixel boundaries for both portrait and landscape.

Additionally, in both cases, I'm using the same texture with the same sampler, the same shader, and the same GL state.

This is what happens when I render the sprite in portrait mode. This is pretty much how I expect it to be rendered (magnified 5x):

[image: Portrait original]

And this is what happens when I render the same sprite in landscape mode.

[image: Landscape original]

My belief is that the framebuffer was created as 768x1024, but when rotated, it is made to fit the 1024x768 screen, squished on the horizontal and stretched in the vertical, and this is what is causing the problem.

If I set OpenTK to create a 1024x1024 framebuffer, the result becomes consistent in portrait and landscape. This is portrait:

[image: Portrait 1024]

Notice how there is be no distortion on the vertical, which happens to be 1024 pixels as well. The distortion is limited to the horizontal, where the resolution doesn't match. This is landscape:

[image: Landscape 1024]

This time the distortion moved to the vertical, supporting my hypothesis.

Furthermore, creating it at 3072x3072, 3072 being the least common multiple of 1024 and 768, the results are correct both in portrait and landscape:

[image: 3072x3072]

Notice that this is not a solution, since not only I'm wasting a lot of memory, but also will create inconsistent multisampling artifacts with 3D, as the vertical scaling is different from the horizontal scaling. Additionally, this is not an option for the iPhone 5, whose resolution of 1136x640 would require me to create a framebuffer of 45440x45440.

Since a device rotation could be thought of as a window resize, I think that the framebuffer has to be recreated to match the new size. This is necessary for Windows on Direct3D. I would have to call `swapChain.ResizeBuffers()` to do this in SharpDX.

I have tried setting `AutoResize = true` in my `iPhoneOSGameView`, but then the framebuffer gets clipped as I rotate the interface, and then everything disappears when rotating the interface again.

I'm not doing anything strange, my framebuffer initialization is pretty vanilla:

```
int scaling = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;
DeviceWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * scaling;
DeviceHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height * scaling;
Size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)(DeviceWidth), (int)(DeviceHeight));
Bounds = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);
Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);
ContextRenderingApi = EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2;
AutoResize = true;
LayerRetainsBacking = true;
LayerColorFormat = EAGLColorFormat.RGBA8;
```

I get inconsistent results when changing `Size`, `Bounds` and `Frame` on my `CreateFrameBuffer` override. Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aOpenTK.Platform.iPhoneOS.iPhoneOSGameView.GraphicsContext) is very incomplete, so I have resorted to randomly changing stuff here and there without really knowing what is going on.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326947/opengl-what-need-to-reconfig-when-rotate-screen) which has no answers. However, I don't know if they're experiencing the same problem as I am.

Also, there is a [similar concern over at the xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13504/opentk-1-0-calling-destroy-createframebuffer-obliterates-context-why), specifically mentioning the rotation issue. There seems to be no solution outside of dropping `GameView` completely.

Is my supposition that recreating the framebuffer is necessary, correct? If so, does anybody know how to do it correctly in OpenTK for Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: Just a side note, perhaps you could check with a 1px checkerboard pattern image to better see whats going on (upscaling, downsampling, texel shift, etc)

Comment: @Krom: I can do that

Comment: what if you don't use device rotation but apply a 90° rotation matrix, will that do the same distortion?

Comment: @bogglez I can do that too

Comment: @Krom: I added more information relevant to your comments

Comment: @bogglez: I added more information relevant to your comments

Comment: @PandaPajama: Now it's much more descriptive! So it looks like texels got shifted uniformly by `~0.3` to the left. Double blur surprises me a lot on a 4th image, as if it got texels shifted and then render shifted. Do you use AA? P.S. Top-left corner pixels got blured everywhere, do you use DXT or alike compression?

Comment: @Krom: I think they're shifted, but not uniformly. Notice how the blur bias is different throughout the image. I'm not using any multisampling, and the texture is a PNG file.

Comment: @PandaPajama: I cannot notice blur non-uniformity, except for the sharp left-most column. However I do notice that checkerboard patterns from top-left corners are all corrupt even on non-blurred renders. Could that be a hint too?

Comment: Could it be, that you suffer from NPOT buffer size? Can you create the 1024x1024 buffer and clip it before display?

Comment: @Krom: As I wrote above, I tried creating the framebuffer at 1024x1024, and I'm closer to an answer. I don't know how to clip it  with OpenTK though...

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot. The projection matrix was scaling everything 3:4, so there's no way I would get pixel perfect renderings. I'm pretty sure this is a framebuffer size issue now, which takes me back to the original question. I have removed all the unnecessary noise from the top of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the renderbuffer must be recreated when the interface is rotated, and set to the new size.

Recreating it is not difficult. However, the renderbuffer ID is private in `iPhoneOSGameView`, and only accessible via the `Renderbuffer` property, which doesn't have a public setter.

Reflection to the rescue! By inspecting `iPhoneOSGameView`, I found out that it contains a field called `renderbuffer` that seems to be quite promising as the backing field behind `Renderbuffer`.

So, when I detect a rotation, I recreate my renderbuffer, and then set it via reflection.

Doing things like this is kinda risky, since I don't really know what else (if anything) I have to change, but so far it looks good.

```
public void ResizeFrameBuffer(int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    DeviceWidth = newWidth;
    DeviceHeight = newHeight;

    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);
    Bounds = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);

    MakeCurrent();

    int renderbuffer = Renderbuffer;

    GL.DeleteRenderbuffers(1, ref renderbuffer);

    GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, Framebuffer);
    GL.GenRenderbuffers(1, out renderbuffer);
    GL.BindRenderbuffer(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, renderbuffer);
    EAGLContext.RenderBufferStorage((uint)RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, (CAEAGLLayer)Layer);
    GL.FramebufferRenderbuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferSlot.ColorAttachment0, RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, renderbuffer);
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);
    GL.Scissor(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);

    var type = typeof(iPhoneOSGameView);
    var renderbufferField = type.GetField("renderbuffer", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    renderbufferField.SetValue(this, renderbuffer);

    Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, DeviceWidth, DeviceHeight);
}
```

`iPhoneOSGameView` never saw it coming...

Answer (score 0):

This is now part of OpenTK.
`iPhoneOSGameView` now has a `ResizeFrameBuffer` method based on @Panda Pajama's answer, which should be called on screen rotation.

https://github.com/opentk/opentk/pull/521